# How to add a cache file to browsers like Chrome/Firefox/etc.?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, browser-cache

For example, there is a website hosting a Shockwave Flash app which is restricted to be used on that specific site. However, the network of the site is poor so that loading the entire .swf from the site will take quite a long time.

Suppose I've got that .swf file somewhere, can I tell the browser "I've owned the file, just use it instead of loading it from the site"?